# How to filter a list using a lookup value field via listdata.svc

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, web-services, spfieldlookupvalue

I have a Posts list(Blog)
I would like to use the rest api call below to filter the list using a lookup value *Category*
When i test it using the Byline field below it works

```
http://Site/news/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Posts?$filter=year(Published) eq 2019 and month(Published) eq 10 and Byline eq 'Test'
```

But when i do something like this below

```
http://Site/news/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Posts?$select=Title,Category/Title,Category/Id&$expand=Category/Id&$filter=year(Published) eq 2019 and month(Published) eq 7 and Category/Title eq 'Events'&$expand=Category
```

I get the error:

```
No property 'Title' exists in type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]' at position 63.
```

Comment: Are you able to change the endpoint? Listdata.svc is deprecated. I recommend you to use the Rest API which is more reliable in long term and allow you to expand lookup field with less troubles.

Comment: yes i can but the issue is i have is i need to extract month and year from the published date like so year(Published) for my filtering but this only works when i use listdata.svc.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use REST API to achieve instead of listdata.svc.

And Category column's internal name is "**PostCategory**", not "**Category**".

A demo for your reference:

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Posts')/items?$select=Title,PostCategory/Title&$filter=PostCategory/Title eq 'Events'&$expand=PostCategory
```

Comment: Thanks Kally. I know i can do this with rest api but the issue is i have is i need to extract month and year  from the published date like so year(Published) but this only works when i use listdata.svc.

Answer (score 0):

So your main trouble is the way to filter date time by year and month through the REST API.
As the listdata.svc is deprecated since a while. I couldn’t recommend to continue your research in that way.

One solution would be filtering the datetime field Published such as the following.

```
/_api/web/lists/list_entity_name/items?$select=Title,Category/Title&$expand=Category/Title&$filter=Published ge datetime’2019-07-01T00:00:00Z’ and Published lt datetime’2019-08-01T00:00:00Z’
```

Or if you can make an HTTP Post request, using the REST API method [GetItems](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245102(v%3Doffice.15)) by passing a CAML query in the body.
But you will not be able to expand the lookup field, to retrieve the value you will have to change or add an extension of your Category field to retrieve the value from the ViewField.

**Request**

> POST /_api/web/lists/list_entity_name/GetItems

**Data**

> {
>     “query” : {
>       “ViewXml” : “Your CAML query”
>     }
>   }